# How to call a JS function inside a JSP?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to call a JS function embedded inside a JSP file from a servlet. I need to pass some arguments to the JS function. Will I be able to do that?

Comment: It depends on what you mean. JavaScript code runs *at the client*, not the server. You can use JSP to *construct* JavaScript code, but the code doesn't run until the JSP has completely finished and the resulting page has been received and interpreted by the browser.

Comment: Usually a Server listen to a Browser. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You have 2 options:

1) Call desired Java functionality using AJAX (mostly used when user do some action):

```
$.ajax('/url/to/your/servlet', {data: 1, another-data: 2}, function() {
     // success callback
});
```

2) Call desired JavaScript function when page is parsed or when it is loaded (prepare the call in JSP page). It is not direct call of JavaScript function from JSP, you just prepare the call and call is performed when page is parsed/loaded on the client side:

```
<script>
    // Alert is show when page is parsed
    alert(${data});
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Alert is show when page is loaded (except of images and few other resources)
        alert(${data});           
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In both cases it is the -browser- (in other words, the client) that invokes the javascript, it is not invoked from the application itself. Note: just adding my thoughts, not a comment on the reply which is good.

Comment: @Gimby yes you're right. It is because it is a JavaScript and JavaScript is used this way in common web apps. If KP. wants invoke JavaScript function really on the server he should include something like JavaScript engine library into his Java application. It is really bed idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why you should not be able to do that. However, note that the JS function will be executed in the **client** side. For example

```
<input type="text" name="user" onclick="submitName(this)"/>
```

can be part of a JSP and will be rendered as part HTML in the response. When the text field is clicked, the submitName() JS function will execute.

Note - This was to just illustrate that JS function call can be embedded in JSP , better way to bind events to HTML elements is to use frameworks like JQuery.